# item type does not belong to known type

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have added a new item type  to  items.xml file named CartProcessDefinition.
After the ANT build and SAP Commerce service startup, the following appears in the log file:

15:56:54****[java][m[0,31mERROR[main][DefaultModelConverterRegistry] code CartProcessDefinition does not belong to known type.Maybe you have added a new type without updating your system.

Is this because I didnt update the system or the new item is missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new item in items.xml, you need to do a "Platform Update" and check "Update Running System".